# Subequations inside table including citations of equations sources

Tags: tables, citing, subequations

I'm converting a Word file into LateX and I'm encountering some issues with subequations within a table...

Here is the Word table I'm trying to reproduce :

[image]

So far I mannaged to use a few answers here to create e table with subequations but it's not quite exactly as the Word version (for exemple, I can't put the equation source AFTER the equation number, my spacing and aligning is quite weird and I'm not sure that putting some \nonumber is the right way to do it) :

```
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Transitions between different powder groups}
    \label{tab:transition}
    \centering
    \rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{flalign}
    &\textbf{Transition}
    &\textbf{Equation}
    \nonumber
    &&\\
    \hline
    &\textbf{C/A}
    & \log(d_p) &= 4.014 - 0.725 \log( \rho_s - \rho_g)       \label{eq:transitionCA} 
    && \text{\cite{B1992A}}\\
    &\textbf{A/B}
    &\log(d_p) &= 5.958 - 1.17 \log( \rho_s - \rho_g) \label{eq:transitionAB}
    &&\\
    &\textbf{B/D}
    &
    \log(d_p) &= 5.425 - 0.807 \log( \rho_s - \rho_g) \label{eq:transitionBD} 
    &&
    \end{flalign}
    \end{subequations}
    \rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
    \end{table}
```

Which results in 
[image]

Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

(since bibliography is not know here, instead reference numbers are present `??`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}r}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Transitions between different powder groups}
    \label{tab:transition}
    \centering
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}c
                                 >{\raggedleft\hsize=0.7\hsize $}X<{=$}@{}
                                 >{\hsize=1.3\hsize $\;}X<{$}
                                 N @{\;}l}
    \toprule
Transition  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Equation}} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                  \\
    \midrule
C/A & \log(d_p) & 4.014 - 0.725 \log(\rho_s - \rho_g) & \label{eq:transitionCA} & \cite{B1992A} \\
A/B & \log(d_p) & 5.958 - 1.17  \log(\rho_s - \rho_g) & \label{eq:transitionAB} & \cite{B1992A} \\
B/D & \log(d_p) & 5.425 - 0.807 \log(\rho_s - \rho_g) & \label{eq:transitionBD} & \cite{B1992A} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \end{table}
see equations \eqref{eq:transitionCA}, \eqref{eq:transitionAB} and \eqref{eq:transitionBD}.
\lipsum*[11]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it work perfectly I tried also to do this with tabularx but it was a complete failure ! Thank you once again !